asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{\varphi(n)}$
This is exercise 17 in Section 2.1 of Multiplicative Number Theory by Montgomery and Vaughan. How to show that for $x\geq 2$,
$$ \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{\varphi(n)}=\log x+C_0+\sum_p\frac{\log p}{p(p-1)}+O(x^{-1/2}\log x)?$$
In the reference by Ward mentioned in the problem. One looks at the infinite sum $\sum_{n} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{n^s}\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} =\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}\prod_p(1+\frac{1}{(p^s+1)(p-1)})$, where the infinite product is absolutely convergent for any $\sigma>0$ and is expansible as an absolutely convergent Dirichlet series $\sum\frac{D(u)}{u^s}$. Then we look at the partial sum $$ \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{\varphi(n)}=\sum_{\nu\leq x}\frac{D(\nu)}{\nu}\sum_{m\leq \frac{x}{\nu}} \frac{\mu^2(m)}{m}.$$
Using the absolute convergence of $\sum \frac{D(u)}{u}$ and the formula for partial sum $\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu^2(m)}{m}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\log x+R+o(x^{-1/2}) $, one obtain
$$ \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\mu(n)^2}{\varphi(n)}=\log x+C +o(x^{-1/2}).$$
This error term is stronger than what is given in the question. Is there a different approach that gives the error term as in the given question?

What have you tried?

@ChristianE.Ramirez I have edited the question.

It seems that the error term becomes $o\bigl( x^{-1/2} \sum_{\nu\le x} \frac{|D(\nu)|}{\nu^{1/2}} \bigr)$ ... how does that turn into $o(x^{-1/2})$?

@GregMartin $\sum_{\nu}\frac{|D(\nu)|}{\nu^{1/2}}$ is convergent

Ah, the series is absolutely convergent (which I think I've convinced myself of), so there's no problem.
